# Protractor automation button click inside '_ngcontent-c6'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

My application has a button, with `_ngcontent-c6` and  i am unable to click on it.

`element(by.css("button[class*='primary-btn']")).click()`

The parent of button -span >class="ng-star-inserted" is being located.

Message:

```
Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, button[class*='primary-btn'])

<b>
<span _ngcontent-c6="" title="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                                <button _ngcontent-c6="" class="button primary-btn">
                                    Create New Request
                                </button>
                            </span> 
</b>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try locator by `xpath` :

```
element(by.xpath("//*[@class='button primary-btn' and contains(text(),'Create New Request')]")).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
element(by.buttonText("Create New Request"))
```

or

```
element(by.css(".button.primary-btn"))
```

If none of solutions provided above won't work (xpath by @Sameer and @Frian or my) make sure to wait until your button is interactive using [Protractor Expected Conditions](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code snippet as well.

```
element(by.xpath("//span[@class='ng-star-inserted']//child::button[@class='button 
primary-btn']").click();
```